# Changing a single property of an object inside of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have such state in my React project:

```
  const [information, setInformation] = React.useState([
    {
      Email: "",
      TellNo: "",
      Username: "",
      NationalityType: "",
      pIDCheck: "",
      VerificationCode: "",
      Password: "",
    },
  ]);
```

I want to update "TellNo" value when input values changes. I tried many approaches like this:

```
     onChange={(e) =>
            setInformation((prev) => [{...prev, TellNo: e.target.value }])
          }
```

but as you can see. it will add an additional object. how can I change my `TellNo` without adding an object

Comment: Do you have only single object in the array ?

Comment: @KcH I didn't get your mean. if you meant getting an additional object alongside of information itself. yes

Comment: currently the state is a an array with an object inside it - `[{}]` and I can see a trailing comma, so do you have state as `[{},{},{}]` and showing us just one `{}` for demo or is it just one obj inside array as it is now in Q
 ?

Comment: @KcH my original state is just single object inside of an array with many properties. but about the code I write. it will give me a single object like this `[{}]` but inside of object itself you will something like this : `0: Object{} 1:Object{TellNo}`

Comment: then the answer below should work

Comment: @KcH. no I get this error `The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the below code:

```
  const [information, setInformation] = React.useState({
      Email: "",
      TellNo: "",
      Username: "",
      NationalityType: "",
      pIDCheck: "",
      VerificationCode: "",
      Password: "",
    });
```

```
onChange={(e) =>
            setInformation({...information, TellNo: e.target.value})
          }
```

and when you wanna send your information you can pass it in an array:

```
[information]
```

Comment: `The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis`

Comment: I missed a curly braces I updated the answer

Comment: adds another object. as before.

Comment: why did you wrap your object in an array?

Comment: I need to send in somewhere but in array form.

Comment: It's better to use your state in object form then when you wanna send it you can do this `[...information]`

Comment: how can I change my `tellNo` in plain object?

Comment: I completed the answer

Comment: Your welcome :) ; If you got your answer please mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

With your current structure, you can try as below ...

```
onChange={(e) =>
   setInformation([{...information[0], TellNo: e.target.value }])
}
```